# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/iid/zzc.class

Tags: java, android, facebook, firebase, adobe

I am making an app in which can edit photos and videos.It also shares edited photos via timeline which is made using Recycler view and Card view.

I am having an error whenever I try to run my app in Android SDK 22 but it is working file in Android SDK 23 and above.

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/iid/zzc.class

It occurs also I am building apk.

Gradle File for my app

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {

     compileSdkVersion 25
     buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
     defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.practice.android.moments"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageName: "${applicationId}"]
}

buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {

    jumboMode true
}
 compileOptions {

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}


/* 3)(Creative SDK) Exclude duplicate licenses */

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    //help
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.1'

compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.11.0'){

    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'

}


compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251'
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4'
compile 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}


configurations.all {




resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can any one please help me...

Phone used for testing

Meizu M2 Note        OS version 5.1       Lollipop          API 22

Redmi Note 3         OS version 6.0.1     Marshmallow       API 23

Samsung Note 5       OS version 7.0       Nougat            API 24

Answer (score 0):

In my case,this error occurs because I have two different version of google-play-service lib.
I remove one of them,bingo!
Try move this compile
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'